# Validate a password input on button submit React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that creates a new user, using name, email, password and role. It validates name and email, but it does not validate the passoword.

This is the function that creates a new user:

```
  const createNewUser = async () => {
  try {
   const response = await axios.post("/user/create", {
     name: newUser.newName,
     email: newUser.newEmail,
     password: newUser.newPassword,
     role: newUser.newRole,
   });
   if (response.status === 200) {
     fetchAllUsers(token).then((res) => {
       dispatch(dispatchGetAllUsers(res));
     });
     setNewUser({
       newName: "",
       newEmail: "",
       newPassword: "",
       newRole: 0,
     });
   }
   else {
     setErrorNew(response.msg); 
   }
 } catch (error) {
   setErrorNew(error.response.data.msg);
 }
};
```

And this is the function that returns error message if input is empty:

```
  const handleChangeNew = (ev) => {
    const { id, value } = ev.target;
    setErrorNew("");
    setNewUser({ ...newUser, [id]: value });
  };
```

I would like to return a error messaje if password input length is less than 6 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
const handleChangeNew = (ev) => {
    const { id, value } = ev.target;
    if(value.length < 6 && id === 'newPassword') {
       setErrorNew("Your password should contain minimum of 6 characters");
    } else { 
       setErrorNew("");
    }
    setNewUser({ ...newUser, [id]: value });
};
```